# Creating a Custom XAML TextBox for Windows 8 Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, custom-controls

I trying to create a custom textbox control in windows 8 XAML.

I've right clicked on my project -> Add -> New Item

I've then selected Templated Control and entered the name MyTextBox

I have then made this class derive from TextBox and added a test Method called Hello. So it now looks like this:

```
public sealed class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(MyTextBox);
    }

    public void Hello()
    {
        //Do something here!
    }
}
```

Within my project a file has also been added called Generic.xaml with the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyTextBox">
                <Border
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So within here I tried adding BasedOn="TextBox" with the Style tag:

```
<Style TargetType="local:WatermarkTextBox" BasedOn="TextBox">
```

This doesn't work.

What do I need to do to create this custom TextBox and then how do I use it within my XAML

This is for a Windows RT so the XAML maybe different from WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of best article and my favorite : [Building a deployable custom control for XAML Metro style apps](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/07/creating-custom-controls-for-metro-style-apps.aspx)

Here is MSDN sample app : [XAML user and custom controls sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-user-and-custom-a8a9505e)

**UPDATE 1 :**

`<Style TargetType="local:WatermarkTextBox" BasedOn="TextBox">`

You don't have to specify `BasedOn` attribute. If you are developing watermark textbox then I would recommend you to check Callisto's watermark textbox code.

[Generic.xaml](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/themes/Generic.xaml#L878)

[WatermarkTextBox.cs](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/Controls/WatermarkTextBox/WatermarkTextBox.cs)

Comment: This article is good but it has nothing about create a control derived from an existing control

Answer (score 0):

BasedOn values can be pointed through StaticResources like `BasedOn={StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}`

I have a NumericOnlyTextBox implementation. Instead of making it BasedOn textbox I've added a textbox and all its dependencies.

In example:

```
<Style TargetType="local:NumericOnlyTextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:NumericOnlyTextBox">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxPart"
                             Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=EnteredText, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             MaxLength="{TemplateBinding MaxLength}">
                        </TextBox>                            
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I tried your example and it's the closest I've got my TextBox to work. I don't want to change anything visually so I just replaced everything within ControlTemplate with: <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxPart" /> but when the textbox is placed within my XAML none of the style and databindings work.